# adjusting axis of 3d cursor

Tags: axis

i have a tube and want make it going around an edge. I usually know how I have to do that but in this case, i cant because the axis of the 3d cursor which I use as pivot point a distorted. how can I get the axis right again? (they should align in this case with the normal word=grid)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your transformation orientation

[image]